# can't access to a wordpress plugin from android AsyncHttpResponseProcess

Tags: php, android, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm editing a Android app (that need to have access to a php wordpress plugin)
I have easily access to that file from browser, but in android there is a problem to have access to that file.
Here is the error :

```
 4321-4321/com.testa.com I/AsyncHttpResponseProcess﹕ Webservice response : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /babak/wp-content/plugins/fruity-feed/shop/home-list.php
    on this server.</p>
    </body></html>
```

any idea have to solve this ? for example by htaccess ?! Its a shared host and I don't have root access to the server.
Its working fine if i use another server....